# executeAsync method for cassandra node js driver

Tags: node.js, cassandra

In cassandra driver for java there is a method like executeAsync(), which reads data from Cassandra asynchronously. Was trying to find if there is a method which does the same task in node js

Answer (score 1):

With the nodejs-driver your only option is async.  When you call `execute` you provide a callback function which gets invoked when the query completes.  You can also consider the `eachRow` and `stream` methods as alternative ways to consume data.

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['h1', 'h2'], keyspace: 'ks1'});
var query = 'SELECT email, last_name FROM user_profiles WHERE key=?';
client.execute(query, ['guy'], function(err, result) {
  assert.ifError(err);
  console.log('got user profile with email ' + result.rows[0].email);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, please consider this. I have 10,000 rows in cassandra instead of reading all rows at once, can i asyncly read i want to read 1000 rows and keep them in one variable, is this possible in nodejs ?

Comment: Take a look at client.eachRow which lets you consume 1 row at a time: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/nodejs/3.0/Client.html#eachRow.  From there you can accumulate an array or object with whatever relevant information you are interested it.